# Unexpected entries in firewall log (ufw)

Tags: firewall, ufw

**Background**

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop. I left all the default settings untouched during installation, and additionally installed google-chrome and VLC.

- The machine is behind a pfSense firewall which blocks all incoming traffic from outside of LAN
- I have configured ufw on the desktop to block all incoming and outgoing traffic, along with some specific allow rules

**Issue**

Within a few hours of installation there were some ufw log entries that I wasn't expecting. I need some guidance on whether these are benign or problematic.

**#1.1**: There are a bunch of outbound UDP attempts to 443. These seem to be headed to Google servers at 1e100.net, and seem related to google "safe-browsing". I am thinking it's better for me to allow these?

```
Jul 23 23:12:55 ubuntu-desktop kernel: [ 2340.289964] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eno1 SRC=192.168.1.35 DST=142.250.176.202 LEN=1278 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22069 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=50783 DPT=443 LEN=1258
```

**#1.2**: But then there is one similar attempt going to infi.net. Couldn't find anything online on them. What Ubuntu functionality would be attempting this?

```
Jul 23 23:32:23 ubuntu-desktop kernel: [ 3508.326964] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eno1 SRC=192.168.1.35 DST=65.206.58.82 LEN=1278 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=42891 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=59228 DPT=443 LEN=1258
```

**#1.3** Then there are a few going to IPs that don't return anything with reverse DNS. Most are similar UDP to 443, but there is one going to 10001 on TCP. Why do I have them?

```
Jul 24 00:10:06 ubuntu-desktop kernel: [ 5771.374520] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eno1 SRC=192.168.1.35 DST=104.16.154.36 LEN=1278 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=23112 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=47937 DPT=443 LEN=1258
Jul 24 00:10:27 ubuntu-desktop kernel: [ 5792.372527] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eno1 SRC=192.168.1.35 DST=45.35.192.162 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1182 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49052 DPT=10001 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

**#2** This one I ask only out of curiosity. What is sending multicast requests like these?

```
Jul 24 00:10:46 ubuntu-desktop kernel: [ 5811.310100] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eno1 SRC=192.168.1.35 DST=239.255.255.250 LEN=635 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=62497 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=39913 DPT=3702 LEN=615
```

**#3** These are the most troubling ones. They look like external IPs trying to access my machine (192.165.1.35). There are some from 1e100.net (UDP), some from deepintent.com (TCP) and others that don't identify themselves. The firewall at my router is supposed to block all incoming requests, so how could such requests even reach Ubuntu? Is my router firewall compromised?

```
Jul 23 23:12:05 ubuntu-desktop kernel: [ 2290.328780] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=74:46:a0:a8:88:8b:00:90:0b:8c:d9:4b:08:00 SRC=142.250.65.206 DST=192.168.1.35 LEN=66 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=443 DPT=45631 LEN=46
Jul 24 00:11:19 ubuntu-desktop kernel: [ 5844.376046] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=74:46:a0:a8:88:8b:00:90:0b:8c:d9:4b:08:00 SRC=169.197.150.7 DST=192.168.1.35 LEN=91 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=48987 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=57286 WINDOW=11 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
Jul 24 01:22:35 ubuntu-desktop kernel: [10120.424253] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=74:46:a0:a8:88:8b:00:90:0b:8c:d9:4b:08:00 SRC=38.91.45.7 DST=192.168.1.35 LEN=91 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=48558 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=34766 WINDOW=11 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer to **#3**, which was also the most pressing. My router firewall is not compromised.

A few minutes passed between my Ubuntu installation and me enabling UFW. During that time my desktop must have reached out to these servers (*on port 443*). When the servers responded, my gateway firewall (*pfSense*) allowed the traffic back in (*appropriately*). But UFW did not see them as responses, and blocked those (*also appropriately*).

Comment: Too much time between the first and last packets for that to be the entire explanation. It is not uncommon for connections to be thought of as closed and forgotten by one firewall, but not by another, and I think that is what is going on here. It is because linux using a half-duplex TCP close sequence verses full-duplex. For your UDP packet, ok. For your port 10001, I only know that between 2021.12.27 and 2022.06.21 my system never tried to initiate a TCP session to that port, but others tried to initiate one with my system 616 times. Yes, UDP to port 443 is very common, you should allow it.

Comment: I also have a Ubuntu server on the same LAN with the same firewall settings. Empty logs for weeks. No one tries to hit the system from the outside (pfSense blocks it), and there are no outbound attempts (which I am positive are due to all the add on programs on the desktop version).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is a conglomeration of multiple apps with different owners.   You could use applications such as lsof to determine what binaries are reaching out to the internet or if you want to be a detective,
follow the money(The owner of the IP space) with ARIN.net, and then correlate those companies' IPs to an app.

eg:
142.250.65.206 = GOOGLE   &&  169.197.150.7 = DeepIntent, Inc.